# Adding a QR Code onto a Resume

Tags: resume, business-cards

I have recently seen people adding [QR Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) to their Resumes or business cards that would lead various things such as career accomplishments, online portfolio or profiles on professional sites like LinkedIn.

Is there any advantage to adding this onto your CV or any distributed documents relating to job hunting or employment opportunities?

Comment: what useful purpose QR serves on a CV?

Comment: @BalogPal - it's a way to maintain an accurate hyper-link after printing to paper. Assuming your CV contains any links.

Comment: I think a very compelling answer for why this might be annoying is if someone puts an answer here which is a QR code link to text on another site.

Comment: @enderland I understand what you mean. I am wondering why there has been a downvote though. Would have thought this would be a decent question to be answered.

Comment: I have a web developer's business card sitting on my desk right now that has a QR code on it. I still have no idea why it's there. If I had to guess it was to try out generating a QR code...In my opinion it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: @crmpicco out of interest do you have a QR Scanner on your phone? And then if you did would you not be curious to find out what was at the end of it?

Comment: Instead of whipping out your phone, finding the QR code app, aiming the camera at the card, and then snapping the photo, you could have just read "http://www.firstname-lastname.com" and typed it into the desktop web browser.

Comment: @MichaelGrubey I do have a QR Scanner on my phone, but I think i've used it once, maybe twice in about 3 years. I agree with Irwin here. Having www.michaelgrubey.com/cv makes much more sense than going to the effort of a QR code.

Comment: QR codes are passe, augment it with Layar Creator ;-) (I've actually seen one example of such a CV, cool stuff).

Comment: @vartec They may be passé in your area, but there are still companies adding QR functionality to their software to this date. I just updated a piece of software that allows user-generated QR codes on electrical schematics. In 2020.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On a resume, a blank QR: definitely not. You're essentially saying "If you want to know more you have to go elsewhere, and I'm not telling you what's there". So you're asking the other to judge the relevance of the QR code and do more work. If your resume is good there's no reason to add the QR code.

On a resume, a well-described QR, saying something like "A portfolio of my latest work can be found here": maybe. If it's not essential information but you're offering it to satisfy the curiosity of the reader, it's OK. If they don't visit the site they should not miss any relevant information. And 'well-described' includes the full URL written out below the QR so that they know here it will take them.

On a business card, yes. There's not much space on the card. But again, the essentials that you did communicate before the existence of QR codes should remain on the card.

Answer (score 2):

There are times when your resume will get printed to paper so the functionality of the hyper-links are lost. These codes can maintain them. You also could be at a job fair passing out your resume in paper form already. I don't know how much a typical HR office would utilize them.

I think it makes sense in places where the recipient has a QR Code scanner (cell phone) available. It could be at a conference or some other business event with a social aspect, but this would be on a business card. It's a convenient way to give someone your resume or portfolio of work.

A shorter URL may be more impressive or just convenient.